# Has Ember.js any add-on to route a request?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

Other frameworks like Backbone have a router component. Does one exist for Ember.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, e.g.

- [SproutCore Routing](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-routing)
- [Ember RouteManager](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager)

You can also use frameworks like

- [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/)

Comment: Routing is now built into Ember as a first class citizen and these other libraries should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Also, checkout [ember-routemanager](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager) which extends SproutCore Routing.

Answer (score 1):

Routing is now built into Ember as a first class citizen.